# How to repeat table's header rows on each page in Reportviewer11 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: rdlc

I am trying to create some reports on ReportViewer 11 with VisualStudio2010. And I want to repeat table header in each page in export execl.
I Set “RepeatOnNewPage” to “True” and “KeepWithGroup” to “After” in Row Groups list.
But it still not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 27):

click on the black upside down triangle to the left of the column groups and go to Advance Mode
[image: advanced mode tiny triangle]

you have to change some of the values for static rows:

```
1)      FixedData        True
2)      KeepTogether     True
3)      KeepWithGroup    After
4)      RepeatOnNewPage  True
```

ok now you may need to read a little more details

[link 1](http://bidn.com/blogs/SMcDonald/bidn-blog/1696/scrolling-column-headers-static-header-columns) 
[link 2](http://olsv.blogspot.com/2010/11/repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-fixed.html)
[last link](http://blog.teamgrowth.net/index.php/net/how-to-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-in-reportviewer-rdlc)

all the above links solve this issue the same way

Comment: This option is not available in the RDLC report, is this image from SSRS .rdl report or an .rdlc report?

Comment: I got errors:

The tablix 'Tablix6' has an invalid TablixMember. All TablixMember elements in a TablixColumnHierarchy must have the KeepWithGroup property set to "None"

All TablixMember elements in a TablixColumnHierarchy must have the RepeatOnNewPage property set to false.

Answer (score 21):

This is most probably a result of not using the default header that comes with the table, but instead adding a row outside the detail group and use it as your header.

Unfortunatly I have not found a way to declar a row as the table header using the designer, the only working option that I have found so far for the RDLC report is via the XML editor as follows:

1. Open up the the RDLC file in the xml editor (right click on the file in VS and select "Open With.." and then "XML Editor")
2. Search for the entry `<Tablix Name="your table name">` (if you have only one table you can emit this step)
3. Search for the entry (before the closing `</tablix>` for the table) 
    `<TablixRowHierarchy>`
           `<TablixMembers>`
4. In the first `<TablixMember>` node (if your headers are on the first row in the table) add the following entry "`<RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>`", so the entry will generally look like this:

   `<TablixMember>`
            `<KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>`
            `<RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>`
            `<KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>`
           `</TablixMember>`

Comment: Worked better than any of the other attempts to describe how to do this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks George this link was helpful for me: http://blog.teamgrowth.net/index.php/net/how-to-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-in-reportviewer-rdlc

"Now, repeat above procedure for all “Static” rows in Row Groups list, except the “Static” rows present under the different group (encircled with black color in following figure), do same for the Details group (encircled with red color):"

My mistake was that I changed values for "Static" row , not for "Details" row also!
After I changed these two values for both Static and Details all works well:
KeepWithGroup    After
RepeatOnNewPage  True