# RDLC report: How can I repeat a group header on each page?

Tags: c#, rdlc

How can I repeat a group header on each page? I have some group that has a lot of rows and thus could not be placed in one single page. I want the group header to put on each pages. I can repeat report-header to repeat on each page but dont know how to repeat group header. Also I am working on rdlc report (not rdl) report.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the solution.
When you don't have grouping in your report, to repeat the headers on other pages is easy. Click on Advanced Mode of property grid - check the property. Go to right panel and set `RepeatOnNewPage` on True and `keeptogether` 'After'. It is easy.

If you have grouping then it gets a little complicated:

1. Select the tablix properties and select "repeat header rows on each page".
2. Click on row groups and select "the top most static" and now click - `RepeatOnNewPage` -True and `KeepWithGroup` After.

Comment: This link does a good job explaining exactly what you are talking about. https://duyanhpham.com/display-row-and-column-headers-on-multiple-pages-microsoft-rdlc-report/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I found a solution and it works like a charm.

First, you need use the Advanced Tablix Member Properties.  The Advanced Tablix Member Properties become available when you click the little arrow on the right side of the grouping pane.
[image]

Then, you need to change the proprieties of the Tablix Member like mentioned in the picture.
[image]

Fore more details, you can check the link below.

https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/8/20/repeating-column-headers-on-every-page-in-ssrs-doesnt-work-o.html

Answer (score 3):

In VS 2005 you can click on the header and see a property in the property grid called RepeatOnNewPage. Just set it to true. (click on the far left panel after clicking on a control in the header)

Answer (score 1):

check out this url
[[How to repeat table's header rows on each page in Reportviewer11 with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846752/how-to-repeat-tables-header-rows-on-each-page-in-reportviewer11-with-visual-stu/16845266#16845266][1])

ie
Open up the the RDLC file in the xml editor (right click on the file in VS and select "Open With.." and then "XML Editor")

Search for the entry  (if you have only one table you can emit this step)

```
<TablixRowHierarchy>
  <TablixMembers>
```

In the first  node (if your headers are on the first row in the table) add the following entry true, so the entry will generally look like this:

```
<TablixMember>
   <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
   <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
   <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
</TablixMember>
```