# How to repeat table header on each page of rdlc when you have two tables in your report in VS2008

Tags: rdlc

I have two tables in my rdlc report. First table contains 7 rows (all are header) which are bind to dataset1. The next table contain the Group header, Details and Footer section which are bind to dataset2. I want to repeat the first table header rows on each page in my report.
Please suggest me the correct solution as I have already tried the options like - "Repeat on New Page Option", "Keep Together" and "Fixed Header" properties, but nothing happened.

Regards,
Anki

Comment: Dataset1 always contains 7 rows? How many columns per row?

Answer (score 11):

To repeat rows with column headings for a table with row groups

*In Design view, select the table. The Grouping pane displays the row groups.

*On right side of the Grouping pane, click the down arrow, and then click Advanced. The Grouping pane displays static and dynamic tablix members for each group. You can only set properties on a static tablix member.

*In the Row Groups pane, click the static tablix member for the row that you want to repeat. When you select a static tablix member, the corresponding cell on the design surface is selected, if there is one. The Properties pane displays the properties for the selected tablix member.

*Set the KeepWithGroup property in the following way:

*For a static row that is above a group, click After.

*For a static row that is below a group, click Before.

*Set the RepeatOnNewPage property to True.

*Preview the report. If possible, the row repeats with the group on each vertical page that the row group spans.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc627566.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Open the report in XML editor and 
follow the steps mentioned in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16845266/4117628

Open up the the RDLC file in the xml editor (right click on the file in VS and select "Open With.." and then **"XML Editor"**)

Search for the entry `<Tablix Name="your table name">` (if you have only one table you can omit this step)

Search for the entry (before the closing `</tablix>` for the table)
`<TablixRowHierarchy>` `<TablixMembers>`

In the first `<TablixMember>` node (if your headers are on the first row in the table) add the following entry `<RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>`, so the entry will generally look like this:

```
<TablixMember>
 <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
 <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage> 
</TablixMember>
```

Answer (score 0):

on the groupings window you need to hit the little down arrow across from "Column Groups" and hit advanced view, select the static row that contains the header columns, the first one, and make sure repeatOnNewPage = true, KeepWithGroup - After