# Repeat data on top of each page in RDLC report

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer

I am trying, with no luck, to get some data to appear at the top of each page in an rdlc report. When the data in the bottom table (Client, Quantitiy, etc.) extends to multiple pages, I need to repeat the fields higlighted in red at the top of every page. Note that the data in red is inside multiple row groups.

[image]

I have seen various posts on SO and MSDN like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846752/how-to-repeat-tables-header-rows-on-each-page-in-reportviewer11-with-visual-stu) that instruct you to open the Advanced Mode for the Groups and change the properties for each static Tablix Member to the following:

[image]

I've tried this approach with no success. I've also tried to selecting each Text Box and changing the RepeatWith property to the name of my Tablix table (Table1), but unfortunately that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does not work as it suggest. Please go to this page and do this. Hope it will work

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2008/10/13/repeat-header-keep-header-visible-in-tables-in-rs-2008/

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is a bit tedious, but I got it working before:

(note - it's easier to start from new table instead of "fixing" existing one)

1. Add all required columns to your new table
2. Add grouping for your table and opt to add group header
3. In your group header row merge all cells into one
4. Place a "Rectangle" control into your merged cell
5. Add all fields into that rectangle - the ones you want to repeat on each page
6. Set "RepeatOnEachPage" property of the row group to True (you have to open row groups in Advanced mode)  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd255242(v=sql.100).aspx

Here is another explanation: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7fce2d58-224e-4435-9571-149458baa2e0/how-to-repeat-rows-on-every-page-in-rdlc?forum=sqlreportingservices

but I found that sometimes it's easier to put everything in one container and deal with visibility/repeating this way.

Comment: I'm afraid you've completely lost me with these steps, beginning at #2. Could you break it down into a 'click here, do this' sequence?