# how to repeat row group header in each page?

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have a parent group and multiple child elements in Tablix of an RDLC report.
The child element count is not fixed for some parents and it goes on to the next page also.

Currently, the output looks as follows (note that my RDLC Report is present in services as a .NET solution):

```
page 1 start here

Parent Group 1 name

       child group 1
       child group 2

Parent Group 2 name

       child group 1
       child group 2 

page 2 start here

       child group 3
       child group 4

Parent Group 3 name

       child group 1
       child group 2
```

But I want the output like so:

```
page 1 start here

Parent Group 1 name

       child group 1
       child group 2

Parent Group 2 name

       child group 1
       child group 2 

page 2 start here

Parent Group 2 name

       child group 3
       child group 4

Parent Group 3 name

       child group 1
       child group 2
```

How can I achieve this? I don't want each parent group on separate pages.
By that, I mean that I don't want to use the Page Break property between each instance of groups.

My main objective is that I want my parent group name to repeat on each page 
if my child elements are expanding more than one page.

Comment: Based on the question, I don't see any difference between the existing output and the desired output.

Comment: in the desired output  Parent Group 2 name is repeating on page 1 as well as page 2 which is not present in existing output.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to specify the `RepeatOnNewPage` property, as per [this forum](https://forums.asp.net/t/1997567.aspx?RDLC%20table%20header%20is%20only%20showing%20on%20first%20page%20i%20need%20to%20display%20it%20on%20all%20pages%20in%20report) on the subject. If you need details on how to do this, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10870143/4851565) on the subject.

Comment: i allready done this  but by this way (i.e RepeatOnNewPage= true ) also i am not getting the proper output.